# Using a protocol with primitive arguments

Tags: clojure, protocols, primitive

I'm trying to define a protocol in Clojure 1.4 with primitive arguments (so that I can avoid unnecessary primitive boxing in performance-sensitive code):

```
(defprotocol A
  (foo [a ^long x]))

(extend-type java.lang.String A 
  (foo [s ^long x] (.charAt s x)))
```

This look like it works OK but fails with an exception when I try to use it:

```
(foo "abracadarbra" 3)
=> ClassCastException XXXX cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn$OLO
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some further reasearch it appears that **protocols do not yet support primitive type hints** (as of Clojure 1.4). See e.g. https://groups.google.com/d/topic/clojure-dev/HxBqIewc494/discussion

Alternatives seem to be:

- Write regular functions with primitive hints. You lose polymorphism.
- Use a Java interface (you can use [reify](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reify) to build instances in Clojure)

Answer (score 2):

take the type hint out of the `defprotocol` and leave it in the `extend-type`

```
(defprotocol A
(foo [a x]))

(extend-type java.lang.String A 
  (foo [s ^Long x] (.charAt s x)))
nil
core> (foo "abracadarbra" 3)
\a
```

or you can change the type hint like so:

```
(defprotocol A
(foo [a ^Long/TYPE x]))

(extend-type java.lang.String A 
  (foo [s ^long x] (.charAt s x)))
nil
core> (foo "abracadarbra" 3)
\a
```

this still produces no reflection warnings without the hint in the `defprotocol`

EDIT:

```
(extend-type java.lang.String A 
  (foo [s ^Long x] (type x)))
nil
core> (foo "abracadarbra" 3)
java.lang.Long
```

Comment: thanks Arthur! this works - but is it actually using the primitive version of the function?

Comment: Hmmm not quite solving the problem then as my intention was to find a way to avoid boxing of primitive arguments.....

Comment: I may be reading that wrong, it's hard to tell because (type 4) reports the same...