# Do Clojure Protocols Support Type Hints?

Tags: clojure, protocols

Do Clojure Protocols support type hints so that the same method name with the same parameters (except for the type hint) can be overloaded like in statically typed languages?

e.g.,

```
(defprotocol IFoo
  (get-val [this ^String astring])
  (get-val [this ^AClass aclass]))
```

If not, can I implement this, or do I have to rename the methods?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a protocol with primitive arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152567/using-a-protocol-with-primitive-arguments)

Comment: Since protocols are for situations in which the dispatch is only on the type of the first argument, they seem inappropriate for this use case where the dispatch appears to be on the types of more than one argument. As @amalloy suggests in a comment, perhaps multimethods might be more appropriate.

Comment: Well one of the things I was trying to do was reuse the implementation of one in the other. I see that's not possible without some way to distinguish the argument types so I guess the only thing is to rename the method based on the function associated with the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, you can't do this with `defprotocol`, still it is possible with `definterface`:

```
(definterface Intf
  (^String add [^String s])
  (^long add [^long l]))

(defrecord Rec [^long data]
  Intf
  (^String add [self ^String s] (str data s))
  (^long add [self ^long l] (+ data l)))

user> (let [r (Rec. 101)]
        [(.add r "asd")
         (.add r 200)])

;;=> ["101asd" 301]
```

Comment: This is true, but `definterface` really is intended only for interop, to give Java code an interface to call methods against. (Personally, I think even in that case I'd rather just write a few lines of Java). For within-Clojure work, just use one of Clojure's methods of dispatch, such as a multimethod.